# getline() reading garbage value while reading from a text file

Tags: c, getline, garbage

In the following code, I want to read the text file with the first line as, `<p> -> <many_declaration> <many_expression>`. The code snippet is as follows:

```
    ssize_t read;
size_t len = 200;
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen(fn ,"r");


if(fptr==NULL){
    printf("Error\n");
    fclose(fptr);
}

else{
    int line_number=1;

    char * line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*200);
    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fptr)) != -1)
    {
        char * tokens = strtok(line, " \t\n");
        
        
        while( tokens != NULL ) 
        {
            
            printf("%s \n",tokens);
            printf("%zu \n",strlen(tokens));
            
            tokens = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
            
        }
        

    }
}
```

However, while reading it using `getline()` in and then splitting the string using `strtok()`, the first token should be `<p>`  of size 3 but the string being read is some invisible characters followed by `<p>` and the length is 6. Could you please tell me what the problem is? Thank you!

Comment: Where is "the following code"? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I edited the question to include the code, but the question seems to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file probably starts with an UTF8 BOM. You should read the file as UTF-8 if so.

Comment: It is a text file I have created using sublime, how do I know if it starts with a UTF BOM?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/581554/66154 -- how the file is saved determines how you should interpret the chars in c. Don't assume that a "char" is the same as a textual character. That's only the case for text encoded in 7 bit ASCII, which excludes most of the worlds texts. See also: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/